# how to view current process state in program output itself

Tags: c, bash, unix, sed, grep

how to print the current process state

```
main ()
{
  pid_t pid;
  printf("parent : %d\n", getpid());
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
    {
      printf("child : %d\n", getpid());
      sleep(2);
      printf("child exit\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  while (1)
    { /*after the child exit, its a zombie process */
      system("clear");
      system("ps -x | grep t"); /* if a.out is Z means zombie process */
      sleep(8);
    }
}
```

Is there any other method or way to view the current process state in output
itself..?

Comment: What bit of state information are you interested in? Whether it's running or sleeping or zombie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining the scheduling state of a process is OS specific. On Linux, `top` and similar read it from the third field in `/proc/$PID/stat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always open and read `/proc` files in C

`/proc/[pid]/stat` and `/proc/[pid]/status` would give the status of the current proces.

The third field in `/proc/<pid>/stat` contains the process status: **R** if it's Running, **S** if it's Sleeping (there's a few others too, like **D** for Disk Wait and **Z** for Zombie).

Or you can parse the output of `ps` command using `popen`. But remember [ps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/download.html) command itself is implemented based on the information from **/proc filesystem**